# How to fetch specific data containing substring from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm trying to get all the albums with specific substring in their name from my local json file.

I can solve this fetching all the albums in the file and filtering them out later, but I want to know if there is a way to fetch only specific albums whose names contain specific substring.

```
function getAlbum(id){
    return from(
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/albums/${id}`)
        .then(response => {
            if(response.status === 404){
                return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/albums`)
                .then(response => response.json());
            }
            else
                return response.json();
        })
    );
}
```

This is my solution so far, as I said, it fetches all albums if it doesn't find one with specific id.

Comment: This should be solved server-side if possible.

Comment: It sounds as though you need to expose another resource, something like http://localhost:3000/albumSearch/${term} or http://localhost:3000/albums?search=${term}.  You won't be able to do this from the client without making those multiple calls.

Comment: You have to do this by server-side filtering. You send the substring you want include in the file name as a filter, and from backend all filtered results will be sent to you upon resolve of `fetch`.